# A family of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Hi everyone: Let $ B(r) $ designate the ball of radius $ r>0 $ and center $ O $ in $ \mathbb{R}^{N} $ and $ N\geq2 $. we know that for all $ \varepsilon>0 $
there exist an infinitely differentiable function $ \varphi_\varepsilon $ with  compact support in $ B(1+\varepsilon) $
and that is equal to $1$ on $ B(1) $. My question is: can we then let $ \varepsilon $ approach zero?! If yes, what do we get at the limit?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Intuitively you are right. It seems that it approaches $ 1_{\overline{B}(0,1)} $. But how would you prove it?

Comment: As a pointwise limit, it is practically self evident you just pick a point. If it's in the unit ball, the functions are alwyas =1 at x. If it's out the unit ball, the functions are eventually zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick some $\epsilon>0$. Since $\phi_\epsilon(x) = 1$ for $\|x\|<1$ and $\phi_\epsilon$ is continuous, we see that $\phi_\epsilon(x) = 1$ for $\|x\| \le 1$.

Hence $\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \phi_\epsilon(x) = 1$.

Now suppose $\|x\|>1$, then choose $\delta={1 \over 2} (\|x\|-1)$. Then if $\epsilon>0$
satisfies $\epsilon<\delta$, we see that the support of
$\phi_\epsilon$ is contained in $B(0,1+\epsilon) \subset B(0,{1 \over 2} (\|x\|+1))$, and hence $\phi_\epsilon(x) = 0$.

Hence $\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \phi_\epsilon(x) = 0$.

This can be written as $\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \phi_\epsilon(x) = 1_{\overline{B(0,1)}}(x)$.

Comment: Very good. Thanks.

Comment: @M.Rahmat: Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the intent of the question, it means: Is there some function equal to $1$ at every point in the ball and equal to $0$ everywhere else and that is infinitely differentiable?

The answer is no because differentiable functions are continuous.  If a function is $0$ everywhere outside the ball and $1$ everwhere inside the ball, then it is discontinuous on the boundary of the ball.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Here is the problem for each $ \varepsilon>0$, take  $ \phi_{\varepsilon}\in C_{c}^{\infty}(B(x,r+\varepsilon)) $ that is =1 on $ \overline{B(x,r)} $. We have:

$$ \int_{B(x,r+\varepsilon)}\Delta\phi_{\varepsilon}d\lambda =\int_{B(x,r)}\Delta\phi_{\varepsilon}d\lambda+\int_{B(x,r+\varepsilon)\setminus B(x,r)}\Delta\phi_{\varepsilon}d\lambda $$
Now,  the integral of the left is 0 ( apply the Green's formula). But the first integal of the right is  $ \lambda B(x,r) $ $, and the second integral approaches 0, if we let $ \varepsilon\rightarrow0 $!! So what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Here is the problem for each $ \varepsilon>0$, take  $ \phi_{\varepsilon}\in C_{c}^{\infty}(B(x,r+\varepsilon)) $ that is =1 on $ \overline{B(x,r)} $. We have:

$$ \int_{B(x,r+\varepsilon)}\Delta\phi_{\varepsilon}d\lambda =\int_{B(x,r)}\Delta\phi_{\varepsilon}d\lambda+\int_{B(x,r+\varepsilon)\setminus B(x,r)}\Delta\phi_{\varepsilon}d\lambda $$
Now,  the integral of the left is 0 ( apply the Green's formula). But the first integal of the right is  $ \lambda B(x,r) $ , and the second integral approaches 0, if we let $ \varepsilon\rightarrow0 $!! So what's wrong?